# Why are histograms generated with qlot() and binwidth = 1 in R displaying widths of length 1.25?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

When plotting histogram with qplot() of ggplot2 package in R, inspite of specifying the binwidth to a particular value, the bar-widths seems unnatural. Why is it so?

I was studying the book "Hands-On Programming with R" and was trying out the following:
 I was to simulate the casting of a double dice and provide the sum of the two numbers as the result of the cast. In order to check the fairness of the dice I can repeat the above experiment (say) 10,000 times and plot the relative frequencies the results (sum of the two numbers) in a histogram. The frequencies should be proportional to the probabilities of getting a certain number as the sum in a single throw of the double dice.

When I plotted the histogram the binwidths seemed unnatural. Besides, the jumps in the heights of the bar seemed to take place at strange interval points. Why is it so?

The following is the code I tried:

```
roll2 <- function(cube = 1:6){
  dice <- sample(cube, 2, replace = TRUE)
  sum(dice)
}
roll2()
rolls10000 <- replicate(10000, roll2())
qplot(rolls10000, binwidth = 1.0)
```

I expect the discontinuities or jumps in the graph to be at integer points like 1,2,3,...
However, the plot shows two such jumps at 2.5 and 7.5 respectively. Please check the  screenshot of the plot in the link provided.
[image: The histogram for the sum of the dice roll 10,000 times]

Comment: Have a quick look at the outputs of `layer_data(qplot(rolls10000, binwidth = 1.0))` and `layer_scales(qplot(rolls10000, binwidth = 1.0))`, which can show you the data and the scales used to render the plot.

Comment: @deepseefan thanks a lot for your answer. I ran those commands and found that the partitions were centered on 1,2,3,...  of width 0.5 on each side. Just one more thing that I needed to know. Could you please shed some light as to how are these intervals lengths decided? Like from 1.5 to 2.5 (0.5 units on each side of 2 etc.). I tried surfing the internet for this. But the answers that are provided require a knowledge of R. Being a novice in this language am unable to understand the answers. Would you please provide some sort of verbose answer as to how the intervals are decided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my understanding.

```r
qplot(rolls10000, binwidth = 1.0)
```

is essentially the same as

```
ggplot(, aes(rolls10000)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1.0)
```

Using `ggplot` we can have more control over the plot and let's add some more details to it.

```r
base <- ggplot(, aes(rolls10000)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1.0)

# let's add a fill and color to the base 
base <- ggplot(, aes(rolls10000)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1.0, fill="#009E73", col="white")
# Adding the limits and breaks of the x-axis
base + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1.5,12.5,1), lim = c(1.5,12.5))
```

That produces the following plot: 
[image: bar_out_one]

Looking at the data that used to generate that output (Useful information including the counts inside each bin and the interval):

```
$data[[1]]
      y count  x xmin xmax density    ncount  ndensity PANEL group ymin ymax colour    fill size linetype alpha
1   293   293  2  1.5  2.5  0.0293 0.1814241 0.1814241     1    -1    0  293  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
2   545   545  3  2.5  3.5  0.0545 0.3374613 0.3374613     1    -1    0  545  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
3   825   825  4  3.5  4.5  0.0825 0.5108359 0.5108359     1    -1    0  825  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
4  1104  1104  5  4.5  5.5  0.1104 0.6835913 0.6835913     1    -1    0 1104  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
5  1348  1348  6  5.5  6.5  0.1348 0.8346749 0.8346749     1    -1    0 1348  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
6  1615  1615  7  6.5  7.5  0.1615 1.0000000 1.0000000     1    -1    0 1615  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
7  1499  1499  8  7.5  8.5  0.1499 0.9281734 0.9281734     1    -1    0 1499  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
8  1084  1084  9  8.5  9.5  0.1084 0.6712074 0.6712074     1    -1    0 1084  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
9   808   808 10  9.5 10.5  0.0808 0.5003096 0.5003096     1    -1    0  808  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
10  575   575 11 10.5 11.5  0.0575 0.3560372 0.3560372     1    -1    0  575  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
11  304   304 12 11.5 12.5  0.0304 0.1882353 0.1882353     1    -1    0  304  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
```

Now getting back to your question **how are these intervals lengths decided?**, is via the **split of the binwidth** if you set one and the **data value at x**. These are used to create the intervals, as shown in the above table.

We can go ahead and experiment with a different binwidth (using `2` this one time) to verify that but you can use your own binwidth.

```r
base <- ggplot(, aes(rolls10000)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 2.0, fill="#009E73", col="white")

base + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,13,1), lim = c(1,13))
```

The output will be
[image: binwidth_out_2]

The data used to render the plot is:

```
$data
$data[[1]]
     y count  x xmin xmax density    ncount  ndensity PANEL group ymin ymax colour    fill size linetype alpha
1  838   838  2    1    3 0.04190 0.2828215 0.2828215     1    -1    0  838  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
2 1929  1929  4    3    5 0.09645 0.6510294 0.6510294     1    -1    0 1929  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
3 2963  2963  6    5    7 0.14815 1.0000000 1.0000000     1    -1    0 2963  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
4 2583  2583  8    7    9 0.12915 0.8717516 0.8717516     1    -1    0 2583  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
5 1383  1383 10    9   11 0.06915 0.4667567 0.4667567     1    -1    0 1383  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
6  304   304 12   11   13 0.01520 0.1025987 0.1025987     1    -1    0  304  white #009E73  0.5        1    NA
```

The last bit of the puzzle is what happens if you don't set the binwidth and the other arguments we assign value explicitly? Default values will be used and you can read the default values from documentation using `?geom_histogram`.

Maybe the above adds something or maybe triggers more questions than the value it adds if there is any.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your final clarification. True that most of the code portions I do not completely understand currently, but will refer to later. However, I get the flow of your answer (how the intervals are decided upon). A more comprehensive answer will probably come form an understanding of the way qplot(x, binwidth = 1) really works.  It really helped a lot. Many many thanks!